# How do I redirect user to another page after submit the form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to redirect the user after submit the form in react JavaScript, example when user submit the form he/she redirect to `google.com` or some other URL with he/she information what he/she entered in the input filed. I created simple with one filed and submit button.

Here my sample code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    firstName: '',
    showName: false
  }
  inputHandler = (e) => {
    let updatedName = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ firstName: updatedName });
    //console.log(updatedName);  
  }
  onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      showName: true
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form
          onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler}>
          <label>Enter the Name</label>
          <input type="text"
            name="firstName" onChange={this.inputHandler} value=
            {this.state.firstName} />
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmitHandler}>Submit</button>
          {this.state.showName && <p>"FirstName: " {this.state.firstName}</p>}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default (App);
```

Comment: This question in duplicated , see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685587/redirect-to-another-page-after-submitting-a-form)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect to another page after submitting a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685587/redirect-to-another-page-after-submitting-a-form)

Comment: no,  @SaeedZhiany

Comment: @Raj If you think your question has something new to ask that the mentioned question does not contain, please provide more details in your question. already what you asked is same as the other questions, good luck!

Answer (score 6):

You can redirect using the this.props.history.push method.

```
  onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
   this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      showName: true
    });
    window.location.href = "someurl/somepage?var1="+this.state.var1+"&var2="+this.state.var2 + "......";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: One thing to be noted: this method is limited to **GET request only**. Other request method like POST cannot be executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Checking(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.username === "" || this.state.password === "") {
      alert("Fields are required");
      return;
    }
    if (this.state.username == "subrata" && this.state.password === "1234") {
      this.props.history.push('/adminpanel')
      return;
    }else{
      alert("Login Failed ! . Check Username and Password.")
    }
     
    console.log(`${this.state.username}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using vanilla javascript to submit the form and redirecting conditionally to the url of your choice**

- This way you do have to manually append the input fields as query parameters while submitting the form.
- This method really shines when you have a large form to be submitted to some url.
- It supports **all http methods** like get post etc.

```js
onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      showName: true
    });
    if(this.state.showName){
      // submitting the form conditionally with javascript
      document.getElementById("nameForm").submit();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form
          onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler}
          id="nameForm"
          action="https://google.com"
          method="GET"
        >
          <label>Enter the Name</label>
          <input type="text"
            name="firstName" onChange={this.inputHandler} value=
            {this.state.firstName} />
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmitHandler}>Submit</button>
          {this.state.showName && <p>"FirstName: " {this.state.firstName}</p>}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
```

inside functional component please use blow codes:

```
const navigate = useNavigate()

navigate("/yourpage");
```