# NextJs ContactUs form redirects to external URL once "submit" is pressed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, contact-form, chakra-ui

I have created contact us form, and I want users of my website to redirect to an external link once the "Submit" Button is pressed after filling the form. The submit button is at the end of code. Here is the code:

```
import {
  Button,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  Input,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalFooter,
  ModalBody,
  ModalCloseButton,
  useToast,
} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { API } from "aws-amplify"
import { createCandidate } from '../src/graphql/mutations'

export const ContactForm = ({ initialRef, onClose }) => {
  const toast = useToast()
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    name: '',
    designation: '',
    companyname: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    comments: '',
  })

  const handleContactFormSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { name, designation, companyname, email, phone, comments} = formState
    if (name && designation && companyname && email && phone && comments) {
      try {
        await API.graphql({
          query: createCandidate,
          variables: {
            input: {
              name,
              designation,
              companyname,
              email,
              phone,
              comments,
            },
          },
        })

        toast({
          title: 'Congratulations',
          position: 'top-right',
          description: 'Successfully submitted!',
          status: 'success',
          duration: 5000,
          isClosable: true,
        })
        onClose()
      } catch (e) {
        toast({
          title: 'Error',
          position: 'top-right',
          description: e.message,
          status: 'error',
          duration: 5000,
          isClosable: true,
        })
      }
    } else {
      toast({
        title: 'Uh-Oh ',
        position: 'top-right',
        description: 'Please verify all fields are filled out.',
        status: 'error',
        duration: 5000,
        isClosable: true,
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ModalHeader>Enter Your Details</ModalHeader>
      <ModalCloseButton />
      <form onSubmit={handleContactFormSubmit}>
        <ModalBody pb={6}>
          <FormControl>
            <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
            <Input
              ref={initialRef}
              placeholder=""
              value={formState.name}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFormState({ ...formState, name: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </FormControl>

          <FormControl mt={4}>
            <FormLabel>Designation</FormLabel>
            <Input
              placeholder=""
              value={formState.designation}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFormState({ ...formState, designation: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </FormControl>

          <FormControl mt={4}>
            <FormLabel>Company Name</FormLabel>
            <Input
              placeholder=""
              value={formState.companyname}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFormState({ ...formState, companyname: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </FormControl>

          <FormControl mt={4}>
            <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
            <Input
              placeholder=""
              type="email"              
              value={formState.email}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFormState({ ...formState, email: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl mt={4}>
            <FormLabel>Phone Number</FormLabel>
            <Input
              placeholder=""
              minLength="10"
              value={formState.phone}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFormState({ ...formState, phone: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </FormControl>

          <FormControl mt={4} >
            <FormLabel>I would like to know about</FormLabel>
            <Input
              placeholder=""
              value={formState.comments}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFormState({ ...formState, comments: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </FormControl>
        </ModalBody>

        <ModalFooter>
          <Button colorScheme="red" mr={3} type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={onClose}>Cancel</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

I have been looking for online references but could not find a solution that guides how to re-direct to an external link once submit is pressed.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How do I redirect user to another page after submit the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52890199/1870780)? You can use `window.location.href = "https://external-url"`.

Comment: @juliomalves this didn't work, unfortunately, I tried to include this in my code didn't work

Comment: Where did you include it exactly? At what point should the redirect happen? When `onClose` is called?

Comment: @juliomalves, actually one line above "onClose", at the "Submit" button.